# stop/delete cron jobs of users who doesn't exist anymore

Tags: cron

How to stop (Delete) the cron jobs of those users who are no longer a part of the Ubuntu server?

Comment: "unix"? We only deal with Ubuntu ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Under Ubuntu, you can view crontab by `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/` and then a file for each user is in there.

So delete those crontabs who's names don't exist in /etc/passwd

I hope this will be work. You can automate it by writing a script to list crontabs and check if corresponding user exist in /etc/passwd or not.

Comment: LOL. Oh and it works ;-)